# AutoIT array missing bracket

Tags: arrays, autoit

I have this array:

```
Global Const $array[70][8] = [[1, ...], [2, ...], [3, ...], ... , [70, 0.48124164, 0.88451159, -8855, -612, 176, 1, 7]]
```

If i run the code, it says "Error: Missing right bracked ')' in expression". If i remove the last element it works. I can't get why the last element is producing this error, and i can't find any syntax error.

I also can compile or build it without any error.
Has anyone an idea what can cause this behaviour?

**//EDIT**
Here is the full array definition:

```
Global Const $array[70][8] = [[1, 0.46382308, 0.37846267223358, 3476, 20, 4, -1, 4], [2, 0.66173166, 0.35245704650879, 4268, -7333, 7, 3, 4], [3, 0.43819791, 0.73096454143524, -5063, 891, 158, 2, 4], [4, 0.49637758, 0.27708977460861, 6028, -1121, 381, 1, 4], [5, 0.60390532, 0.37993001937866, 3503, -5119, 83, 2, 4], [6, 0.43493705, 0.50274324417114, 415, 1054, 130, 3, 4], [7, 0.5436604, 0.88573443889618, -9015, -2928, 52, 1, 3], [8, 0.51811683, 0.60228180885315, -1968, -2021, 95, 1, 3], [9, 0.55463874, 0.84207928180695, -7663, -3285, 70, 1, 3], [10, 0.48325252, 0.79658991098404, -6724, -746, -272, 1, 3], [11, 0.5183885, 0.8305846452713, -7633, -1877, -272, -1, 3], [12, 0.55923116, 0.68494528532028, -3946, -3505, 36, 2, 3], [13, 0.48257315, 0.8402858376503, -7837, -644, -262, 2, 3], [14, 0.55860614, 0.70989108085632, -4713, -3447, 36, 2, 3], [15, 0.42719244, 0.61063778400421, -2193, 1338, 70, 2, 3], [16, 0.41371411, 0.57615393400192, -1314, 1882, 48, 2, 3], [17, 0.50219285, 0.79606002569199, -6684, -1330, -272, 2, 3], [18, 0.47042638, 0.43658798933029, 2099, -196, 97, 2, 4], [19, 0.42469245, 0.41934603452682, 2529, 1427, 265, 3, 4], [20, 0.43958377, 0.52923792600632, -262, 827, 92, 2, 4], [21, 0.49751889, 0.78456538915634, -6454, -1299, -268, 2, 3], [22, 0.48034489, 0.50571876764297, 363, -592, 21, 4, 3], [23, 0.39637708, 0.53408849239349, -372, 2397, 39, 3, 4], [24, 0.39023572, 0.64112710952759, -2920, 2726, 75, 2, 4], [25, 0.41588801, 0.64752662181854, -3116, 1715, 51, 2, 1], [26, 0.45412194, 0.81338351964951, -7201, 402, 24, 3, 4], [27, 0.50868737, 0.36688649654388, 3793, -1674, 248, 2, 4], [28, 0.5741769, 0.25597554445267, 6584, -4035, 661, 4, 4], [29, 0.52428531, 0.59066486358643, -1700, -2216, 97, 2, 4], [30, 0.43132287, 0.72403514385223, -5038, 1220, 51, 1, 4], [31, 0.51977443, 0.34100317955017, 4459, -2070, 1206, 2, 4], [32, 0.4120565, 0.59812414646149, -1975, 1930, 62, 3, 4], [33, 0.59803569, 0.29261976480484, 5669, -4950, 805, 3, 4], [34, 0.4343664, 0.67442893981934, -3846, 1152, 154, 5, 4], [35, 0.46480131, 0.91842484474182, -9804, -73, 67, 3, 7], [36, 0.56852471, 0.84611463546753, -7977, -3894, 9, 1, 8], [37, 0.47779053, 0.32180470228195, 4813, -401, 349, 2, 4], [38, 0.52241027, 0.30594861507416, 5344, -2175, 1278, 2, 4], [39, 0.52458423, 0.6877578496933, -4022, -2207, 94, 3, 1], [40, 0.55643224, 0.88345181941986, -8904, -3372, 16, -1, 8], [41, 0.43931204, 0.35995709896088, 3888, 772, 5, 3, 4], [42, 0.54311692, 0.80111443996429, -6882, -2920, 22, -1, 8], [43, 0.42798048, 0.70581495761871, -4682, 1328, 94, -1, 4], [44, 0.3859694, 0.54077327251434, -486, 2956, 63, -1, 4], [45, 0.47751879, 0.33729392290115, 4491, -594, 283, -1, 4], [46, 0.43974685, 0.33378851413727, 4621, 945, 53, 1, 4], [47, 0.51083415, 0.31422311067581, 5179, -1736, 1338, 3, 4], [48, 0.45425778, 0.89918559789658, -9241, 309, 262, 3, 7], [49, 0.36626821, 0.71910309791565, -4933, 3595, 10, 3, 4], [50, 0.550481, 0.33325856924057, 4563, -2943, 1062, 4, 4], [51, 0.45588821, 0.8790088891983, -8811, 306.7, 346.9, 3, 7], [52, 0.54849743, 0.403449177742, 2900, -3145, 177, 3, 4], [53, 0.59265524, 0.30664157867432, 5234, -4822, 691, 3, 4], [54, 0.42800766, 0.74604618549347, -5443, 1265, 20, 3, 4], [55, 0.4743666, 0.874076783, -8673, -364, 191, 1, 7], [56, 0.45151323, 0.957066357, -10774, 383, 25, 3, 7], [57, 0.47893184, 0.984906196, -11285, -681, 121, 4, 7], [58, 0.50632327, 0.886182785, -8951, -1578, 94, 3, 7], [59, 0.52273643, 0.937378764, -10108, -2216, 49, 4, 7], [60, 0.52306246, 0.924375951, -9920, -2244, 27, 4, 7], [61, 0.54613327, 0.291233837, 5638, -3031, 1559, 1, 4], [62, 0.54523652, 0.89673995, -9217, -3016, 20, -1, 8], [63, 0.50667655, 0.897432863, -9184, -1735, 73, 2, 7], [64, 0.53928542, 0.9322021, -10176, -2685, 5, 2, 7], [65, 0.5081439, 0.97875124, -11280, -1734, 0, 1, 7], [66, 0.45591539, 0.87778604, -8811, 315, 348, 4, 7], [67, 0.53086143, 0.92669934, -9956, -2405, 37, 2, 7], [68, 0.49053514, 0.938356995, -10244, -1009, 47, 1, 7], [69, 0.43232834, 0.950096189, -10584, 1205, 31, 1, 7], [70, 0.48124164, 0.88451159, -8855, -612, 176, 1, 7]]
```

The code around looks like

```
EndFunc

Global Const first[54][8] = ...
Global Const $second[29][8] = ...
Global Const $array[70][8] = [...] // error array
Global Const $last[30][8] = ...

Func function($first)
```

Comment: Could you please post a complete array definition which causes the problem

Answer (score 0):

Look like a fat finger:

```
Local  $arr[3][3] = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, (.00, 0.1575818700]]
```

> ==> Missing right bracket ')' in expression.:

Comment: I searched in the definition for "(", no results. So there is no opening bracket.